# QT 6.3 convert QVector to std::vector

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qt6

I am converting my code from QT 5 to QT 6
[image]

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#toStdVector

I have came across this, when noticing toStdVector() function was removed.
until now I had a line of code like this

```
collection.dgValues = imageset.digitalGainValues().toStdVector();
```

I am now suppose to change it into this?

```
std::vector<analoggain_type> ag_vec(imageset.analogGainValues().begin(), imageset.analogGainValues().end());
collection.agValues = ag_vec
```

or is there a nicer way to code this?

Comment: You don't need the variable `collection.agValues = std::vector<analoggain_type> (imageset.analogGainValues().begin(), imageset.analogGainValues().end());`

Comment: You does not need to create a variable for that conversion, you can so it inline, but yes afaik thats how this should be done.

Comment: Or  using `vector::assign` like this `collection.agValues.assign(imageset.analogGainValues().begin(), imageset.analogGainValues().end());`

Comment: I guess, depending on what `analogGainValues()` returns - a temporary object or a reference to an existing one, you may or may not wish to save its result first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

However, it is worth noticing that [there is no use for QVector anymore](https://www.qt.io/blog/qlist-changes-in-qt-6) since Qt 6 made it an alias to QList, so you should migrate your code away from it.

> However, we decided that QList should be the real class, with implementation, while QVector should just become an alias to QList.

Prefer to use QList as a rule of thumb. QVector is history.